# libraries in eclipse

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!

I am trying to set the libraries and include paths for Gazebo in eclipse but I am not sure how it should be done. Does anybody know which Path and Symbols configuration is needed?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3516/libraries-in-eclipse/) by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you followed Gazebo tutorials you should have a CMake project. Thus, you can generate Eclipse project with all necessary paths and symbols automagically by:

```
$ cd build
$ cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ../
```

As a result you will get `.project` and `.cproject` files in the `build` directory. Just import the project into Eclipse workspace (File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Select root directory (choose `build` directory in dialog)).

However, sometimes for code completion to work it is necessary to add additional symbols and paths. That can be done by the following sequence: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols -> Add Contributed... -> Discovered scanner configuration container, Next -> Next -> Select everything (yes, by hand) in "C/C++ Container path" -> Finish. It can be tiresome, but eventually it helps.

Also you may need to try to compile project at least once, thus Eclipse gather output information from compiler.

**Note:** The next problem you may face is "Out of memory" error while sources are indexing. In short, Eclipse allocate 256 Mb of memory (or so) by default. Which seems ridiculously small for Java VM, and you have to give it more to cope with Gazebo sources. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm) you can read how to do it. To permanently save these settings edit `eclipse.ini` appropriately in the root directory of Eclipse.

P.S. That all works for sure on Juno, but should be pretty similar on Indigo.

---

**EDIT:**

The libraries can be added by using `target_link_libraries` in `CMakeLists.txt`

**Note:** It is necessary to re-generate Eclipse project files every time you change `CMakeLists.txt`

**EDIT 2:**

There is actually a [better way](http://answers.ros.org/question/61407/standard-system-include-paths-missing-in-eclipse-from-catkin_make/?answer=69880#post-id-69880) to solve indexing problem. Instead of doing "Add Contributed..." as described above, do Project -> Properties -> [C/C++ General] -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> (Choose tab "Providers"), tick "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings" and, possibly, "CDT GCC Build Output Parser". This one definitely works in Eclipse Kepler, but I'm not sure for previous versions.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-17**:
Thanks for your answer, but I had a problem when following the steps you mentioned. When I get to "C/C++ Container path" the list is empty, and I cannot finish the configuration. Any ideas why?

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-18**:
So... I got it! But I still have problems. Like "Symbol ModelPlugin could not be resolved". Is there any other configuration to change in the project?

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-18**:
So... now it worked. I just did all over again. Don't know what was wrong before. Thanks!

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-07-18**:
Glad it helped. The last resort is usually to delete `build` directory and start over, and it is usually the way for catkin packages in ROS. Sorry, didn't get any notification of your comments before.

**Comment by [atenea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/403/atenea/) on 2013-07-19**:
That's what I did. Thanks again.